# Why doesn't `finally` work in this case in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This does not print "drag end":

```
mouseDrags.forEach(drag => {
    console.log('drag start');
    drag.finally(_ => console.log('drag end'));
    drag.forEach(doSomething);
});
```

But this prints "drag end":

```
mouseDrags.forEach(drag => {
    console.log('drag start');
    drag.finally(_ => console.log('drag end')).forEach(_=>_);
    drag.forEach(doSomething);
});
```

Why does the forEach make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `.finally()` returns another Observable which you need to subscribe to. `Observable`s are by default lazy, so they won't start emitting until they are subscribed to.

So you can do

```
mouseDrags.forEach(drag => {
    console.log('drag start');
    drag.finally(_ => console.log('drag end')).forEach(doSomething);
});
```

or even better

```
mouseDrags.flatMap(drag => {
    console.log('drag start');
    return drag.finally(_ => console.log('drag end'))  
}).forEach(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `drag`? If it is an Observable, you need to subscribe to it. `finally` doesn't subscribe, but `forEach` does. You could test it by calling `drag.finally(_ => console.log('x')).subscribe()`. That should print it too.

[The forEach is in fact an alias for subscribe](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md), so using either is fine.